# A binomial sum problem

Tags: abstract-algebra, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

I m following the book "Concrete Mathematics"
Let $m,\alpha,\beta$ be positive. Please let me know where am I getting wrong in the below calculation?

\begin{align}
&\sum_{k}\binom{m+\beta-1}{m+k-1}\binom{m-k}{m-\alpha}(-1)^k\\
 &= (-1)^{m-\alpha}\sum_{k}\binom{m+\beta-1}{m+k-1}\binom{k-\alpha-1}{m-\alpha}(-1)^k \quad (\text{by upper negation on page 174})\\
&= (-1)^{m-\alpha}(-1)^{2m+\beta-2}\binom{-m-\alpha}{-\alpha-\beta+1} \quad \text{by 5.24}\\
&=0
\end{align}

But the left hand side is not vanishing.

Comment: Can you explain why the last term is zero? do you have any constraints on $m, \alpha, \beta$? thanks

Comment: For example, $\binom{-2}{1} =0$.

Comment: @Lau, because as mentioned at the top $m, \alpha,\beta$ are positive. So the value of the binomial term $\binom{-m-\alpha}{-\alpha-\beta+1}$ is zero.

Comment: @dust05, any thought on this, where am I getting wrong?

Comment: (1) I've looked up the book; $\binom{-2}{1}  = -2 \ne0$ in this book definition. Sorry. I think for integer $n$ and $k$, $\binom{n}{k} = 0$ when $k<0$ but not for negative $n$ in general. (so anyway the RHS is zero.) (2) Thus, the summand in the first equation is nonzero when $1-m \le k \le \min\{\alpha, \beta\}$. In this range of $k$, the left hand side seems vanishing.

Comment: I asked for constraints on $m, \beta, \alpha$ because  here https://arxiv.org/pdf/1105.3689.pdf  authors said that given $n$ a negative integer and $k$ an integer then $\binom{n}{k}\neq 0$ if $k\geq 0$ or $k\leq n$.

Comment: when $k, \alpha,\beta$ lie between $1$ and $m$ then the left hand side is not zero. I have checked it.

Comment: My point is that the given sum is for $k= 1-m, \dots, \min\{\alpha, \beta\}$ not $1\le k \le m$. For example for $m = 5, \alpha = \beta=2$, then $$ \sum_{k} \binom{6}{4+ k} \binom{5-k}{3}(-1)^k.$$ The $\binom{6}{4+k}$ term does not vanish when $0\le 4+k \le 6$, i.e. $-4 \le k \le 2$.The second term is not vanishing when $5-k<0$ or $5-k \ge3$, i.e. $5<k$ or $k \le 2$. So the $k$ which makes the summand nonzero is $-4 \le k \le2$, and the summands are $84, -336, 525, -400, 150, -24, 1$ for $k = -4, \dots, 2$ respectively, and their sum is $0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your calculation is fine and there's nothing wrong with it. Here we treat this identity slightly different without using the formula (5.24) from *[Concrete Mathematics](https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/%7Er97002/temp/Concrete%20Mathematics%202e.pdf)*
by Don Knuth et al.

We use the common definition (5.1) for the binomial coefficients with $r\in\mathbb{C}$
\begin{align*}
\binom{r}{k}=\begin{cases}
\frac{r(r-1)\cdots(r-k+1)}{k!}\qquad&\text{integer}\ k\geq 0\\
0\qquad&\text{integer}\ k<0
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
and we also use the *coefficient of* operator $[z^k]$ to denote the coefficient of $z^k$ of a series. This way we can write for instance
\begin{align*}
\binom{r}{k}=[z^k](1+z)^r\tag{1}
\end{align*}

> We obtain with positive integers $m,\alpha,\beta$:
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}}&\color{blue}{\binom{m+\beta-1}{m+k-1}\binom{m-k}{m-\alpha}(-1)^k}\\
> &=\sum_{k\geq -m+1}\binom{m+\beta-1}{m+k-1}\binom{m-k}{m-\alpha}(-1)^k\tag{2}\\
> &=\sum_{k=0}^{m+\beta-1}\binom{m+\beta-1}{k}\binom{2m-1-k}{m-\alpha}(-1)^{k-m+1}\tag{3}\\
> &=\sum_{k=0}^{m+\beta-1}\binom{m+\beta-1}{k}\binom{-m-\alpha+k}{m-\alpha}(-1)^{k+\alpha+1}\tag{4}\\
> &=(-1)^{\alpha+1}\sum_{k=0}^{m+\beta-1}\binom{m+\beta-1}{k}[z^{m-\alpha}](1+z)^{-m-\alpha+k}(-1)^k\tag{5}\\
> &=(-1)^{\alpha+1}[z^{m-\alpha}](1-z)^{-m-\alpha}\sum_{k=0}^{m+\beta-1}\binom{m+\beta-1}{k}\left(-(1+z)\right)^k\tag{6}\\
> &=(-1)^{\alpha+1}[z^{m-\alpha}](1-z)^{-m-\alpha}\left(1-(1+z)\right)^{m+\beta-1}\tag{7}\\
> &=(-1)^{\alpha+1}[z^{m-\alpha}](1-z)^{-m-\alpha}(-z)^{m+\beta-1}\\
> &=(-1)^{\alpha+\beta+m}[z^{-\alpha-\beta+1}](1-z)^{-m-\alpha}\tag{8}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=(-1)^{\alpha+\beta+m}\binom{-m-\alpha}{-\alpha-\beta+1}}\tag{9}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=0}
> \end{align*}
> and the claim follows.

*Comment:*

- In (2) we note $\binom{m+\beta-1}{m+k-1}=0$ if the lower index $m+k-1<0$.
- In (3) we shift the index $k$ to start with $k= 0$. We observe that $k$ is restricted due to the upper index of $\binom{m+\beta-1}{m+k-1}$.
- In (4) we use the binomial identity $\binom{-p}{q}=\binom{p+q-1}{q}(-1)^q$.
- In (5) we use the *coefficient of* operator according to (1).
- In (6) we do some rearrangements and use the linearity of the *coefficient of* operator.
- In (7) we apply the binomial theorem.
- In (8) we apply the rule $[z^{p-q}]A(z)=[z^p]z^qA(z)$.
- In (9) we select the coefficient of $z^{-\alpha-\beta+1}$ and since the lower index $-\alpha-\beta+1<0$ the result $=0$ follows.

**Example: $\alpha=2,\beta=6,m=3$**; A small plausibility check to see the formula in action.

> \begin{align*}
> \sum_{k}&\binom{m+\beta-1}{m+k-1}\binom{m-k}{m-\alpha}(-1)^k\\
> &=\sum_{k}\binom{8}{2+k}\binom{3-k}{1}(-1)^k\\
> &=\sum_{k=-2}^6\binom{8}{2+k}(3-k)(-1)^k\\
> &=5\binom{8}{0}-4\binom{8}{1}+3\binom{8}{2}-2\binom{8}{3}+1\binom{8}{4}\\
> &\qquad-0+(-1)\binom{8}{6}-(-2)\binom{8}{7}+(-3)\binom{8}{8}\\
> &=5\cdot 1-4\cdot 8+3\cdot 28-2\cdot 56+1\cdot 70-0+(-1)28-(-2)8+(-3)1\\
> &=5-32+84-112+70-0-28+16-3\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=0}\\
> &(-1)^{\alpha+\beta+m}\binom{-m-\alpha}{-\alpha-\beta+1}=(-1)^{11}\binom{-5}{-7}\,\,\color{blue}{=0}
> \end{align*}

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Actually in my question $1\leq k \leq m$. I think then the answer should not be zero. Because when I m running the binomial sum on L.H.S. of the equation, it's nonzero.

Comment: @prince: You're welcome. If you restrict the index range to $1\leq k\leq m$ you usually can't apply the table identities without adaptation. Note the authors explicitly state in this section the validity of the identities in the corresponding table is given iff $k\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: right, I was guessing the same. How should I proceed then? Any tip please?

Comment: @prince: You might want to start with $\sum_{k=1}^m\cdots$ by yourself. If you can't find a closed formula, just write another question this time with the index range you want to work with. Maybe you also want to refer to this question to point out the differences. Kind regards,